# Problemas para acomodar el "aside"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy avanzando con el código HTML de mi página y tengo un problema con una página que no está tomando una propiedad de CSS que las demás si. En principio tengo configurada las páginas para que ocupen una section el 63.5vw del total (que se mantiene a la izquierda) y el section destinado a aside el 35vw del total (con position:sticky). En principio este compilado consta de 3 páginas webs de las cuales las 2 primeras toman estas propiedades pero la tercera página no. He estado revisando el código y las clases para ver si hay algo que no esté funcionando correctamente pero no detecto el error.

En la primer y segunda imagen se ve que funciona correctamente, en la tercer y cuarta se ve como no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
.main {
/* Posicionamiento de las dos secciones: article y aside */
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.article--grid {
/* Width del artículo (es temporal hasta implementar flex de manera completa)*/
width: 63.5vw;
}
.aside--grid {
width: 35vw;
}

.aside {
/* Configs de los Contenido+ de las páginas (donde se encuentren) */
position: sticky;
top: 30px;
margin: 15px;
border: solid 3px #000;
background-color: #7CACD4;
border-radius: 25px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO DE LA QUE SI FUNCIONA (no corresponde al ejemplo pero en este caso es otra pagina que si funciona con las propiedades aplicadas)

```html
<main>
        <div class="article--grid">
            <article>
                <section class="section">
                    <p class="section__text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae nemo
                        sequi quas quod dolore itaque eveniet eos. Molestiae sapiente laboriosam reiciendis, ipsum quos,
                        facere voluptatem modi magnam illo eaque consequuntur.
                        Consectetur ab vitae incidunt quia eos ducimus quas reprehenderit, ipsum dicta animi, nobis
                        magni, quo sint hic quasi ea at id. Tempore alias quidem voluptates veritatis eos totam
                        assumenda dignissimos!</p>
                </section>
                <section class="section">
                    <h2 class="section__h2">titulo en h2</h2>
                    <h3 class="section__h3">titulo en h3</h3>
                    <p class="section__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita beatae
                        dicta facilis, quam fugit voluptatibus enim ut ducimus deserunt repudiandae voluptatum minima,
                        repellendus et est. Quos numquam quas quod veniam.
                        Eos nisi dolorum similique autem repudiandae corporis sint cupiditate quibusdam ab aliquid, quas
                        minus doloremque commodi ut, sunt incidunt dicta ratione fugit deserunt iusto unde rerum vel.
                        Sed, qui vitae.</p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="aside--grid">
            <article class="aside">
                <h2 class="aside__h2">Contenido+</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a class="aside__link" href="https://www.carthrottle.com/post/dovde4l/" target="_blank">GALERÍA</a>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a class="aside__link" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iAe99_2g1YQ" target="_blank">VIDEO
                    PROMOCIONAL</a>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/4FtDFYQDrHIyvHxuG6AAh5?si=8BRX1FnrQO23lMIpVarnTw">SOUNDTRACK
                    OFICIAL</a>
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>
```

CÓDIGO DE LA QUE NO FUNCIONA (tercer y cuarta foto)

```html
<main>
        <div class="article--grid">
            <article>
                <section class="section">
                    <p class="section__text">En este apartado daremos a conocer algunas de las colecciones TCG de Hot
                        Wheels que no han tenido la misma fama que Acceleracers™ y Mega-Race, pero que sin duda alguna
                        forman parte de la historia de la marca orientadas sobre todo a los aniversarios y autos
                        clásicos de la marca que siempre han representado un legado en la marca.<br>
                        Las siguientes colecciones, de las cuales se encuentra información suficiente como para
                        demostrar en este apartado, son las siguientes: </p>
                </section> 
                <section class="section">
                    <h3 class="section__h3">Hot Wheels 1993 Maxx™ 25th Anniversary</h3>
                    <p class="section__text">"Celebra la magia de Hot Wheels con estos cromos de edición coleccionista.
                        Veinticinco de los autos más memorables de 1968 a 1992 cobran vida en este set a todo color con
                        estampado especial de láminas plateadas. ¡Revive la historia de cómo comenzó tu colección
                        hoy!"<br>
                        El objetivo de esta colección fue conmemorar el 25° Aniversario de la marca Hot Wheels en el
                        mercado,
                        a través de estas 25 cartas de colección e intercambio de autos icónicos de la marca que
                        enamoraron a niños y adultos,
                        y en colaboración con la empresa MAXX Race Card INC dedicada a la producción y distribución de
                        barajas
                        de cartas coleccionables e intercambiables relacionadas al mundo del automovilismo
                        estadounidense: principalmente
                        de NASCAR.<br>
                        Puedes encontar la galería completa externa en el link de Contenido+.</p>
                    <div class="section__div--img">
                        <img class="section__img" src="../multimedia/otrascartas/mustang-front.jpg"
                            alt="frontmaxxmustang">
                        <img class="section__img" src="../multimedia/otrascartas/mustang-back.jpg"
                            alt="backmaxxmustang">
                    </div>
                    <ol class="section__list">
                        <li>Nombre del Modelo Exhibido: se puede observar el nombre del auto real como el número de
                            producto en la empresa Mattel</li>
                        <li>Especificaciones del Auto: Especifica marca, año de salida, variaciones del modelo (al
                            momento del 25° Aniversario), nombre del modelo, número del producto y número de carta de la
                            colección. </li>
                        <li>Breve Descripción: comentando sobre algunas características del modelo en escala.</li>
                    </ol>
                </section>
                <section class="section">
                    <h3 class="section__h3">Hot Wheels 1999 Comic Image™ Collector Cards</h3>
                    <p class="section__text">"Durante más de 30 años, la marca Hot Wheels ha gobernado el camino de los
                        autos de juguetes, simbolizando la historia del amor de Estados Unidos por el automovilismo.
                        Comic Image™ coloca a los fanáticos en el asiento del conductor con esta espectacular serie de
                        72 tarjetas impresas en cartón Metal-Tex™ de asombrosa calidad. La serie captura los aspectos
                        destacados en los 31 años de historia de Hot Wheels hasta las introducciones de productos del
                        año 2000. Busca en los paquetes las seis tarjetas tipo <span class="italic">chase</span> de Kyle
                        Petty insertadas al azar."<br>
                        El objetivo de esta colección fue conmemorar el 30° Aniversario de la marca Hot Wheels en el
                        mercado, a través de estas 72 cartas de colección e intercambio de autos icónicos de la marca, y
                        en colaboración con la empresa Comic Image™ dedicada a la producción y distribución de juguetes
                        y coleccionables de distintos tópicos.<br>
                        Puedes encontrar la galería completa externa en el link de Contenido+.</p>
                    <div class="section__div--img">
                        <img class="section__img" src="../multimedia/otrascartas/deora-front.jpg" alt="frontcideora">
                        <img class="section__img" src="../multimedia/otrascartas/deora-back.jpg" alt="backcideora">
                    </div>
                    <ol class="section__list">
                        <li>Nombre, imagen y año de producción del Auto</li>
                        <li>Breve Descripción: comentando sobre algunas características del modelo en escala.</li>
                    </ol>
                </section>
                <section class="section">
                    <h3 class="section__h3">Hot Wheels 2000 Serie Maestra - Serie Complementaria</h3>
                    <p class="section__text">"¡Colecciona, personaliza y compite! Colecciona las 140 cartas y
                        personaliza tu baraja para crear el máximo sistema de carreras. ¡Compite con tus amigos y sé el
                        primero en llegar a la meta! Busca todos los sistemas de juego de cartas de colección Hot
                        Wheels. Puedes encontralas en: Baraja Maestra con todo lo necesario para pasar de la cochera a
                        la pista, Paquetes Complementarios de 10 cartas que es como tener tu propio mecánico. ¡Apodérate
                        de los máximos autos de carreras!"<br>
                        El objetivo de esta colección estuvo relacionado en un principio a una prueba-piloto en el
                        mercado latino (ya que únicamente las cartas se comercializaron en Centro América y América del
                        Sur) para lo que mas adelante conoceríamos como Hot Wheels Acceleracers™. Este juego consta de
                        una baraja inicial con aproximadamente 60 cartas e instrucciones del juego y los paquetes
                        complementarios de 10 cartas para sumar a tu baraja principal.
                        Se divide el juego en cartas de:</p>
                    <ul class="section__list">
                        <li>Autos: en su totalidad son diseñados por la marca (por cuestiones de copyright), en donde se
                            muestran datos que aportan a la dinámica del juego.<img class="section__img--li" src=""
                                alt="imagenauto">
                            <ol class="section__list">
                                <li>Nombre del Auto</li>
                                <li>Tipo de Cubiertas: asociado con los Potenciadores</li>
                                <li>Tipo de Auto</li>
                                <li>Restricciones del Auto</li>
                                <li>Número de Potenciador Permitido</li>
                                <li>Velocidad Límite del Auto</li>
                                <li>Descripción de la carta</li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li>Pistas: <img src="" alt=""></li>
                        <li>Potenciadores: <img src="" alt=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="section__text">Lamentablemente, no se encuentra disponible la colección completa en internet, por lo que no hay
                        contenido extra a mostrar por el momento. ¡Pero siempre estamos trabajando para incorporar nueva
                        información a fin de que puedan tenerla disponible </p>
                </section>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="aside--grid">
            <article class="aside">
                <h2 class="aside__h2">Contenido+</h2>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a class="aside__link" href="https://www.carthrottle.com/post/dovde4l/" target="_blank">GALERÍA</a>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a class="aside__link" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iAe99_2g1YQ" target="_blank">VIDEO
                    PROMOCIONAL</a>
                <div>

                </div>
                <a href="https://open.spotify.com/album/4FtDFYQDrHIyvHxuG6AAh5?si=8BRX1FnrQO23lMIpVarnTw">SOUNDTRACK
                    OFICIAL</a>
            </article>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por llegar hasta acá! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad `width` determina el ancho de la parte de contenido.

Entonces tenemos: 63,5% + 35% = 98,5% del viewport. A eso hay que agregarle 30px del margen del aside + lo que tenga de margen la columna de la izquierda.

Calculo que el primer ejemplo está a un pelito de mandar el aside para abajo por falta de espacio, y en el segundo algo (probablemente el OL) aumentó el margen un poquito y el ancho ya no alcanzó para tener las dos secciones lado a lado.

El "layout inspector" de Firefox (o su equivalente en otros navegadores) te puede servir para encontrar dónde está ese margen rebelde.

**Agrego:** recién chequeé y vi que el padding no está incluido por default en el `width` (yo creía que sí). Así que agregando `box-sizing: border-box` quizás quepan ambas secciones.

Answer (score 0):

He probado con achicar los vw incluso hasta valores en donde debería funcionar (el article en unos 50vw y el aside en unos 20vw) y aún así se mantiene en la parte de abajo! Con respecto a la propiedad border-box, esta se encuentra en la primera línea del CSS:

```
 * { 
    /* Medidas Resets de las páginas */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

mas un normalize.css vinculado a todas las html

**Agrego** ENCONTRÉ LA SOLUCIÓN. Aparentemente el problema se encontraba en el normalize.css y donde se encontraba ordenado en mi head. Alguna vez escuché que no debemos de poner tantas propiedades en el head porque conforme se van a agregando mas, la página tarda mas en cargarse. Me puse a revisar en el head y resulta ser que el normalize.css era la última hoja de estilos linkeada (la propia estilo.css y la normalize.css después) mientras que en las demás estaban al revés en orden: primero normalize y luego la hoja propia. Cambiando el orden de las mismas pude solucionar el problema. Muchas gracias!